# Почему обособлено наречное сочетание " в свою очередь"?

Tags: вводные-слова, невыделение-вводных

Я просматривала **предложения из Нацкорпуса**, где есть словосочетания "***в свою очередь",*** и мне показалось, что многие примеры не соответствуют **[правилу Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122) пункт 9(7)** о прямом и  переносном значении. Вот, к примеру, **текст М. Булгакова:**

*— Славно! — сказал Стравинский, возвращая кому-то лист, и обратился к Ивану: — Вы — поэт? — Поэт, — мрачно ответил Иван и впервые вдруг почувствовал какое-то необъяснимое отвращение к поэзии, и вспомнившиеся ему тут же собственные его стихи показались почему-то неприятными. Морща лицо, он, **в свою очередь**, спросил у Стравинского: — Вы — профессор?*

Мне кажется, что здесь **прямое значение словосочетания,** но почему оно тогда **обособлено?**  Вед персонажи **по очереди** что-то говорят друг другу.

**Или вот такой пример** из недавней темы: *Предложение состоит из двух блоков, // причем вторая часть  **в свою очередь** / тоже состоит из  блоков.*

У меня нет никакого желания обособлять "в свою очередь", а по правилам вроде бы нужно обособлять.  В предложении такой простой структуры обособление выглядит **неуместным.**

**И вывод:** Может быть, на семантику мы ориентируемся сначала, а потом **корректируем решение по структуре?**